# What is the main functional difference between these two jQuery ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've seen these two kinds of ajax calls, what is the main functional difference between them?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'post',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'post',
    data: {}
}).success( function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: first is ok, second one is ok but deprecated, use .done() callback instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first adds a success callback to the ajax method.

The second adds a success callback to the *promise* interface that `$.ajax` returns.

I actually don’t think there is a `success` method on the deferred object that `$.ajax` returns (maybe there is a legacy in an older version), it should be `done` according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'post',
    data: {}
}).done( function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: promise interface exposes success method but it is deprecated

Comment: As a side note, ajax() doesn't return a deferred object but a promise interface like you stated firstly. Difference is promise interface is read only, you cannot resolved/rejected it

Comment: I can't see any difference between these two as from the callstack both of them seems to be using the deferred framework. look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S3kGD/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between those 2 snippets. Even though you are using the option property `success` internally it is getting added to the promise callback list of the ajax request.

[image]

If you look at the attached image you can see that the value passed to `success`, `error` and `complete` are passed back to the jqXHR object's callback methods